# Flex - Security error accessing URL - ERROR#2042

Tags: xml, flex3

I've built a flex Web-app that has a login in function. However the user information that it uses to verify the user is stored in a sqlserver DB on a different domain. For some reason i can only log in on a certain machine and only with chrome, when i try with IE8 or on a different machine it outputs the 2042 error.
I've thoroughly searched for the answer to this and have found that the problem is something to do with new versions of flash player and setting my cross-domain file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
   <cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false" />
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Has your back end server a crossdomain.xml file? Or did you use the loadPolicyFile?
Did you use allowDomain to explicitely allow the 2d domain?

Comment: Okay, so i have played around with it and i have tried just setting the crossdomain to allowDomain="*". The crossdomain file is located in the root of the server the swf is trying to communicate with. I've scowered article after article trying different things and i cant seem to figure out whats wrong with it.